# difference between %s and %S

Tags: pointers, go

I was learning Go recently. This is something about Go pointer.

Here is the code:

```
var house = "Malibu Point 10880, 90265"
ptr := &house

fmt.Printf("ptr type: %T \n", ptr)
fmt.Printf("address: %p \n", ptr)

value := *ptr

fmt.Printf("value type: %T \n", value)
fmt.Printf("value: %S\n", value)
fmt.Printf("value: %s\n", value)
```

The tutorial is coded as line 3 with `%s` but with `%S` it gives this strange result:

```
ptr type: *string
address: 0xc000010200
value type: string
value: %!S(string=Malibu Point 10880, 90265)
value: Malibu Point 10880, 90265
```

The `%s` should be the string value of this pointer, but what does `%S` mean?

Comment: `%S` is an unknown verb. See this sample run: https://play.golang.org/p/wVQDRLCpH3I. Consider [creating an issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/new/choose) if it's not already been created on GoLang repo for the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: The verb `S` is unknown. The output `%!S(string=Malibu Point 10880, 90265)`  is the [documented](https://godoc.org/fmt) output for an unknown verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%S` is not a valid fmt verb. The output you're getting is equivalent to `%p`. There's nothing special about `%S`. This appears to happen with any unrecognized verb.

```
fmt.Printf("value: %p\n", value)
fmt.Printf("value: %S\n", value)
fmt.Printf("value: %L\n", value)
fmt.Printf("value: %A\n", value)

value: %!p(string=Malibu Point 10880, 90265)
value: %!S(string=Malibu Point 10880, 90265)
value: %!L(string=Malibu Point 10880, 90265)
value: %!A(string=Malibu Point 10880, 90265)
```

This behavior is from [`badVerb`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/fmt/print.go#L330) which is [called when you give a bad fmt verb](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/fmt/print.go#L458). It's documented in "Format errors" in the [`fmt` docs](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/).

> Format errors:

> If an invalid argument is given for a verb, such as providing a string to %d, the generated string will contain a description of the problem, as in these examples:

> Wrong type or unknown verb: %!verb(type=value)